# What functions should I disable if I would allow users to type PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say I want my users to allow to create PHP scripts on my page and I would save those pages in directory. What functions should I disable to not be hacked? Or what should I do?

Firstly, I would not allow people to upload files through PHP file (not sure how to do it yet), what else?

Comment: You can allow your users to create any PHP script as long as you just save those pages and don't plan on ever running them on your server :-)

Answer (score 2):

In such case I'd not let them execute PHP files though its possible ro run them by disabling thousands of function.

For this **Its better to allow user to write** [xml](/questions/tagged/xml).  A parser would have read it and execute it accordingly. Most programming language feature can be implemented in [xml](/questions/tagged/xml). See how [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) does it. There is *loop*, *conditional statement* etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make PHP into a safe language by blacklisting individual functions -- there are simply too many which can be used maliciously.

Comment: Don't let your users upload executable code. Back up, reevaluate what you're trying to do, and go about it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

- File handling (`fopen`,`fclose`,`fwrite`,etc.)
- File browsing (`opendir`,`readdir`,etc.)
- Execution (`exec`,`shell`,etc.)
- Remote file access (`allow_url_include` php.ini directive)

And anything else you may see as being harmful. put yourself in the place of a "Cracker" and what ways would you use to see your system or environment and disallow anything you see as being harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than retype all of the useful stuff in this fellow stackexchange site, I provide you a link sir: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/disable-insecure-dangerous-php-functions

And a few functions:

"apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, eval, exec, fp, fput, ftp_connect, ftp_exec, ftp_get, ftp_login, ftp_nb_fput, ftp_put, ftp_raw, ftp_rawlist, highlight_file, ini_alter, ini_get_all, ini_restore, inject_code, mysql_pconnect, openlog, passthru, php_uname, phpAds_remoteInfo, phpAds_XmlRpc, phpAds_xmlrpcDecode, phpAds_xmlrpcEncode, popen, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exec, syslog, system, xmlrpc_entity_decode"

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the other way around. I would provide the users a subset of PHP that they can use.

Then, you only have to validate that what they sent is contained in that safe list.

Also, you can create your own functions to replace some of the dangerous ones.